# the group $ \ S_4 \times S_3 \ $ has a normal subgroup of order $ \ 72 \ $.

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Show the group $ \ S_4 \times S_3 \ $  has a normal subgroup of order $ \ 72 \ $.

**Answer:**

Since $ A_4 \ $ is a  normal subgroup of $ S_4 \ $ ,  $ \ \ \ A_4 \times S_3 \ $ is a subgroup of $ S_4 \times S_3 \ $.

Now  $ o(A_4 \times S_3 ) \ =12 \times 6=72 $ , which is the half of the order of  $ S_4 \times S_3 \ $.

Hence $ A_4 \times S_3 \ $ is a normal subgroup of $ S_4 \times S_3 \ $ of order $ 72 \ $ .

**My question is** - why did not we consider here  the subgroup $ S_4 \times A_3 \ $ whose order also $ 72 \ $ ?

Is $ \ S_4 \times A_3 \ $ a subgroup of $ \ S_4 \times S_3 \ $ ?

If not , then how would I show this ?

I am confused.

Is there any help ?

Comment: We could've looked at $S_4\times A_3$ just as well, it is a normal subgroup of order $72$. The question is not "find all normal subgroups of order $72$", it is "show that there is at least one".

Comment: I know  $  A_4  \times S_3  $ is normal  subgroup of order 72 . . But  My question is -why did not consider the subgroup $ S_4 \times A_3 \ $ ?

Comment: We could've considered either. It doesn't matter.

Comment: There's no reason why not consider $S_4\times A_3$ though...

Comment: But some says $ S_4 \times A_3 \ $ is  not normal subgroup . I am confused right here . Can  I get any clarification ?

Comment: @mabmath Who is "some"?

Comment: Of course $S_4 \times A_3$ is a normal subgroup. It has index $2$.